# Construct date column from year, month and day in Polars

Tags: python, python-polars

Consider the following Polars dataframe:

```py
import polars as pl
df = pl.DataFrame({'year': [2023], 'month': [2], 'day': [1]})
```

I want to construct a date column from `year`, `month` and `day`. I know this can be done by first concatenating into a string and then parsing this:

```py
df.with_column(
    pl.concat_str([pl.col('year'), pl.col('month'), pl.col('day')], sep='-')
    .str.strptime(pl.Date).alias('date')
)
```

But that seems like a detour. Is it possible to construct it directly with the three inputs? Something like this (that doesn't work):

```py
import datetime
df.with_column(
    datetime.date(pl.col('year'), pl.col('month'), pl.col('day')).alias('date')
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

polars has a [`pl.datetime`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.datetime.html) and [`pl.date`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.date.html) function that works the same as base `datetime` except that it takes expressions so you can just do

```
df.with_columns(pl.date(pl.col('year'), pl.col('month'), pl.col('day')).alias('date'))
```